# Ruling on showing the waist (men)

Tags: human-body, awrah

Well as the question says, is it permissible to show the waist? (with pants covering the lower body of course)

Comment: The male 'awrah is from the navel to the knee according to the majority view. There are already posts on this on the site.

Comment: Some relevant posts [What is the awrah for men should a man lower his gaze on seeing another shirtless man?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40241/what-is-the-awrah-for-men-should-a-man-lower-his-gaze-on-seeing-another-shirtl) and [Is man torso/chest/trunk 'awrah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28607/is-man-torso-chest-trunk-awrah)