# Areas to be covered for men while praying

Tags: salat, awrah

I wanted to know what part of men in Arwah and which is not? From [this](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/125425) website it mention 2 things.

> The man’s ‘awrah is between the navel and the knee, and some of them
>   include the navel and the knee in the ‘awrah.

From what we learn from elders that it is between naval and knee. So does a shorts just covering over knee valid for praying?  I have heared someone said when u sit, if the shorts come to the thighs it is not valid namaz?

Comment: Basically there's a difference of opinion on this matter and it is better to leave any doubt and take the most covering option. And I guess if you added the tag [tag:awrah] you may even find similar questions on the site. Like [What is the 'Awrah of men ...](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40241/13438) which might be a helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From below knee to above naval and shoulders. But showing a greater modesty is always great.